# Google Vision API Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"images\" at 'requests[0]'

Tags: google-cloud-platform, postman, google-vision

I want to use [Google vision API](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/detecting-text#vision-text-detection-protocol) using Postman or any other rest api tool.

1. So as per documentation I convert my image to base64-encoded-image-content using Java 8 encoding as below :

   ```
   byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(path);

   // getting base64 encoded string bytes

   byte[] bytesEncoded = Base64.getEncoder().encode(data);

   String encodedData = "{ \"content\": \"" + new String(bytesEncoded) + "\" }";
   ```
2. Now in postman I choose Post option and then use the URL as https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=keyVal
3. And then in the body part I choose raw option and paste the below content

`{ "requests": [ { "images": { "content": "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" }, "features": [ { "type": "TEXT_DETECTION" } ] } ] }`

But I am getting an error :
`"Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"images\" at 'requests[0]': Cannot find field."`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a typo in the documentation. The documentation for [AnnotateImageRequest](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/images/annotate#AnnotateImageRequest) says the attribute should be named "image", **not** "image**s**".